# Is it possible to find silence in audio file using python?

Tags: python-2.7, audio

I want to find silence in a audio file. And then get their start and end time. I never work with audio file in python. So I need specific tutorial or book suggestion, which will help me.

Comment: Start by checking out the [`wave` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by getting a measurement of the power of an audio signal. There's actually a function that does this using RMS (root-mean-square) in the stdlib: [audioop.rms.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/audioop.html#audioop.rms)

Note that "silence" is rarely actually silent (at least in recorded audio), so you have to determine a reasonable threshold for silence.

-cymrow ([Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/49edrg/how_to_find_silence_and_its_starting_time_ending/))